# In WPF WebBrowser, Authorize page has lots of script errors and buttons don't work

Tags: wpf, stocktwits

in our WPF desktop app we pop up a window to display the StockTwits authorize page when the user wants to authorize our application to share tweets. The window contains a WebBrowser control. When we show the window, several scripting errors popup:
[image]

Once the user clicks through all the script errors and signs in, more script errors appear. The Connect button appears, but clicking on it or Cancel does nothing.
[image]

Clicking Sign Out at the top creates an IE error page
[image]

This is on Windows 10 Anniversary, which has IE 11 installed.

Comment: I think web browser use vanilla version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @AbinMathew forgive my ignorance but how does that relate to the issue I'm having? I'm not sure what you mean by "vanilla version."

Comment: Hi, the default version of IE in web browser control use different version than the one which is installed on your machine/Where ever the application is. So things works in IE-11 may not work with web browser control. To make it work i believe you have to set the version somewhere in registry(Google). Hope this helps.

Comment: i think default version of IE in web browser control is vanilla version similar to IE-7.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I'll look into that.